Schengen area ban and EU freedom of movement
This may be similar to the 5 year ban question earlier asked, but I believe there are some areas of divergence. Last year I got a 2 year ban for visa overstay in Denmark, my husband became a EU citizen 3 months ago so we want to exercise the treaty right in the Netherlands or Sweden or Norway, will the ban allow me to register as a spouse of an EU citizen?.

I was told that an over stay ban takes priority over any other consideration

Denmark particularly do not lift ban

Netherlands can not issue the treaty right residence even if they want to, because in all cases of overstay, a member state can not override the ban issued by another another member state.

On the Norwegian Immigration's website ie UDI, It stated that people with BAN and schengen alert can not enjoy free movement right treaty

HOWEVER, I heard that the only positive thing going for me is that the marriage has been done years back in our country before even coming to Europe, so the issue of bogus marriage is ruled out completely.


Please I need your good contribution, and if possible some one point me to any piece of legislature in the EU that substantiate the fact that over stay ban ought not to hinder the enjoyment of free movement treaty right.
Thank you wonderful people
PLEASE I WILL LIKE TO ADD AN UPDATE TO THE POST.
Good day, all. Please I wanted to add some more information as per update. I have applied to Danish immigration to put the deportation on hold based on my new status as an EU family member; unfortunately, they refused the request and insist on the deportation Please what else can I do to stop the deportation.
Meanwhile, I have made requests for the removal of the SIS alert on my name and also the entry ban,as I write, I am still waiting for the outcome.

This question is similar to: 5-year entry ban in 2015 by Swedish authorities. In 2018 I got married to my Irish wife. Should I wait until 2020 when the ban expires?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Legally it shouldn't be an issue, the earlier question gets into some details but a ban for an overstay is not in and of itself enough to block someone from exercising their (derived) freedom of movement rights.

I was told that an over stay ban takes priority over any other consideration No it doesn't and the answer to the other question also covers that. A ban following a criminal conviction is obviously more serious than an overstay ban and even that doesn't automatically disqualify you. The general principle is the same, the only thing that can legally be use to justify refusing a visa to join your EU spouse is that you pose a current danger to “public safety, public health, or public policy”, nothing you did in the past. The answer won't change.

OTOH, if your questions is about how to go about it in practice, you need to ask about that specifically and provide a lot more details. The more general answer is that if the authorities disregard the rules and somehow prevent you from entering, you'll need a lawyer to figure out the details.

Note that marrying abroad doesn't really guarantee anything regarding the status of your marriage. French authorities for exemple might check that you physically live together and have denied residence permit when they think they have proof that the applicants do not really behave as a married couple.

I just noticed your comment from July 23 and will edit my answer to address it.



I was told that an over stay ban takes priority over any other consideration


Who told you this?  They're wrong.  Rights under the free movement directive take priority over the restrictions of the Schengen codes and national law.

On the Norwegian Immigration's website ie UDI, It stated that people with BAN and schengen alert can not enjoy free movement right treaty

I think I see what you are talking about.  For example, the page for Residence card for family members of EU/EEA nationals says

You must not be subject to a prohibition against entry to Norway or Schengen.

I believe this is likely the result of a misinterpretation of the Schengen Borders Code, which says at Article 6(1)(d)


For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:

...
(d) they are not persons for whom an alert has been issued in the SIS for the purposes of refusing entry;

This is not as straightforward as it seems, because there is a counterintuitive definition of "third-country national" at article 2(6):


‘third-country national’ means any person who is not a Union citizen within the meaning of Article 20(1) TFEU and who is not covered by point 5 of this Article;


Article 2(5) reads


‘persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law’ means:

(a) Union citizens within the meaning of Article 20(1) TFEU, and third-country nationals who are members of the family of a Union citizen exercising his or her right to free movement to whom Directive 2004/38/EC of the European Parliament and of the Council ( 1 ) applies;
(b) third-country nationals and their family members, whatever their nationality, who, under agreements between the Union and its Member States, on the one hand, and those third countries, on the other hand, enjoy rights of free movement equivalent to those of Union citizens;

Thus, when you are traveling with your EU-citizen husband, Article 6 does not apply to you and your entry ban, which would otherwise require you to be excluded under article 6(1)(d), is irrelevant.
Instead, the law governing your admission is the free movement directive.
The problem, then, is to get the Norwegian authorities to recognize this.  Since their interpretation is very formally expressed on their website and through the administrative procedures detailed there, this seems unlikely without a lawyer and possibly a court.  Without hiring a lawyer, you can do one or both of the following:

complain that the information on the website is inconsistent with EU law and ask them to justify the inconsistency.
request clarification on the policy through Your Europe Advice
if your nationality requires you to apply for a visa, you can submit the application so you have a formal refusal in hand.

Once you have a formal statement of the policy, preferably citing the legal basis of the policy, you can try taking it to SOLVIT.  If that doesn't work, you'll probably need a lawyer or to choose a different country.

I just noticed your comment from July 23rd on a deleted answer:

Thank you all for always being there. If I may ask, do they have the right to come and grab me and put me forcefully on the next flight?. The question ,may sound stupid, please I just need help with your input.

They always have that right under some circumstances, but as the spouse of an EU citizen, you can't be expelled from an EU country if you are there with your spouse, unless the authorities of the country find that you are a serious threat to public safety, public health, or public policy.  The requisite seriousness is such that this is essentially inapplicable to almost everyone.  Even a person who has been convicted of a serious crime must be shown to be a present risk to public safety; the past conviction on its own is insufficient to justify the finding.
So, assuming that you are in the large majority of people who cannot be expelled under the free movement directive, you would only be expelled if the authorities challenge the applicability of the directive in your case.  For example, user Relaxed has noted the possibility that they would not recognize your marriage.  This is probably unlikely, but it does happen.

A visa or residence card application would force a review of the previous ban under the new conditions set out in Article 27 (which an simple overstay would not fullfill) of the Freedom of Movement. Second Paragraph of 27 (2): The personal conduct of the individual concerned must represent a genuine, present and sufficiently serious threat affecting one of the fundamental interests of society. Justifications that are isolated from the particulars of the case or that rely on considerations of general prevention shall not be accepted.

@MarkJohnson but Norway says you have to apply first, separately, for the ban to be lifted before you can apply successfully for a visa.  In theory, at least, it ought to be possible for a ban to be kept in place, so a banned family member of an EU citizen would be able to visit the Schengen area only with the EU citizen.  Obviously that's less important in cases where the family is seeking to establish residence in the Schengen area.

A judge will make a determinantion based on what is written in the Directive 2004/38/EC and not what is written on a website.

@MarkJohnson of course.  But it shouldn't be necessary to go as far as putting the question to a judge.  The fact that the (official) website seems to show this misinterpretation, however, implies that it might be.  At least it looks as though a Norwegian government lawyer would have to be involved to get Norway to change their administrative procedure.

@phoog, I appreciate your response. what happpens now that my spouse is yet to move physically to the country where I currently live,  we have kids as well, and the whole thing is happening so fast, can I challenge this deportation at least before she can move in to my country ?. Can the courts come in .

If your EU-citizen spouse is outside of the EU, then they are not exercising their freedom of movement right. You, as the spouse of an EU-citizen, can only take advantage of their freedom of movement right when traveling with (or joining) the EU-citizen. Therefore you are a 3rd country national that must abide by the immigration laws as any other 3rd country national must.

But she is also in the EU, we are just in a different EU country, and she is relocating to join me very soon (a few weeks ), It is just the problem with moving and kids.

Please all what are your thoughts? what options may be left for me now to put a stop to the deportation process

@FelisDebemni if your spouse is in a different EU country but planning to join you then the situation is far from clear.  The most obvious option to resist deportation would be for your partner to move immediately to the country that is trying to deport you.  You can try pointing out to the authorities that your EU-citizen partner is planning to move there and you will just come back as soon as she does; they might in that case decide to save themselves the hassle and expense and just let you stay, but they wouldn't have to.

To address the comment by @MarkJohnson to account for the information that your partner is not outside the EU, I would note that your partner being in a different EU country from you still leaves you as a "third-country national" who lacks free movement rights unless you are traveling to join your partner or residing with her.  So another option would be for you to do just that: go to your partner and stay with her for the few weeks before she moves to your country. For any other course of action I would seriously consider trying to find a good lawyer (not an easy task in itself, of course).

@FelisDebemni another thing to look into is your children, who may have acquired EU citizenship from your partner.  If one of them can move to your place immediately then you would have additional rights to remain where you are.  These are not explicit in the directive but have arisen from various court cases where it was found that the non-EU parent of an EU citizen child has some right to remain with the child in the EU.  I am less familiar with these provisions, so if you can bring one of your children to live with you immediately then you may want to post a new question about these rights.

These are really great insights, concerning this statement
'...unless you are traveling to join your partner...'
So if I choose to move to be with my partner quickly because is less cumbersome for me to move, am I covered by the law as regards crossing EU borders, because I understand that the ultimate condition is for the EU CITIZEN to be travelling with the non EU citizen for the non EU to enjoy the right. So can I travel alone wihout the EU citizen ?

@FelisDebemni Yes, with one major exception! A citizen of an EU Member state does not exercise their freedom of movement right when residing in their country of citizenship. As long as your spouse is not a citizen of Denmark and joins you in Denmark, then the freedom of movement right applies (otherwise Danish national laws applies). If you joint a Danish citizen in another EU county and then return to Denmark, then the freedom of movement right also applies (the EU citizen has exercised their freedom of movement right with their non EU-citizen spouse).

Hmmmm, so it means that I can not enjoy this right when I,  the third country national move quickly to the EU citizen in the country she is a citizen of, The movement must be outside of the country issuing the passport. Additionally, may I kindly indulge a bit further, with the ban still in place and the Schengen alert still active, can I just leave Denmark and move to another EU country to exercise the right? the reason I asked the question is because of the active Ban, althought I have applied for it's removal( will this not been seen again as another ofence of violation of immigration rules

Hello once again, the authority sent me this as per my request to delete my name from the SIS :  After a thorough assessment, the Return Agency has determined that your information registered in SIS cannot be deleted.
Legal Basis According to Article 3 of Regulation 2018/1861, Member States are required to enter reports into SIS concerning third-country nationals who are subject to a return decision, in accordance with Directive 2008/114/EC.
This provision is implemented in Danish law under Section 58 g, subsection 3, of the Aliens Act.

The provision is implemented in Danish law under Section 58 h, subsection 1, of the Aliens Act. According to Article 14 of Regulation 2018/1860, return reports are also deleted when the decision that formed the basis for entering the report has been withdrawn or annulled by the competent authority. Return reports are also deleted when the third-country national in question can prove

that they have left the territory of the Member States in accordance with the respective return decision. It is also stipulated that return reports are deleted when the third-country national has obtained citizenship in a Member State or any state whose citizens are entitled to free movement under EU law.

According to Article 53, subsection 4, of Regulation 2018/1861, after an application for access, correction, or deletion, the Member State informs the data subject as soon as possible and in any event within the time limits referred to in Article 12, subsection 3, of Regulation 2016/679, about the outcome of the exercise of the rights under this article, regardless of whether the data subject is located in a third country or not.

Furthermore, it follows from the recitals of the above-mentioned regulations and directives that Ireland is not covered by the provisions. The Member States of the mentioned regulations and directives thus consist of EU countries (except Ireland) and the Schengen-associated countries (Switzerland, Norway, Liechtenstein, and Iceland).
Therefore, we do not find grounds to delete your return report.

In making this assessment, we have considered that Article 3 of Regulation 2018/1860 stipulates that Member States enter reports into the SIS concerning third-country nationals who are subject to a return decision in accordance with Directive 2008/114/EC.
We emphasize that Ireland is not considered a Member State under the provisions of Directive 2008/114/EC and Regulation 2018/1860. Therefore, your spouse's acquisition of Irish citizenship does not impact your return decision and report.

If you are dissatisfied with our assessment, you may file a complaint with the Danish Data Protection Agency.
